# Slow loops in Perl

Tags: performance, perl, loops

The following subroutine takes 12 seconds in my computer to execute:

```
sub trans() {   
    $trans = "";
    foreach $nuc (@array) {
        foreach $k (keys %hash) {
            if ($nuc eq $k) {
                $w = $hash{$k};
                $trans .= $w;
                last;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code continues generating a file with the content of $trans. It takes, as I said, 12 seconds. The problem is that I have to produce 256 output files...... and it takes too long.....

Any idea for optimizing it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following

```
sub trans() {   
    $trans = "";
    foreach $nuc (@array) {
            if ($hash{$nuc}) {
                $w = $hash{$nuc};
                $trans .= $w;
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing!!! My first code took 12 seconds but with your help it takes less than 1 second!! Many thanks, David!

Comment: Hi, The reason is that in the question we iterated for every item of the array over all keys of the hash which has a complexity of O(number of keys) and in the result we check the hash directly which has a complexity of O(1). For more information of how it works please look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 11):

Why do you loop over every key in the hash just to test whether it equals a known value?

```
sub trans() {   
    $trans = "";
    for my $nuc (@array) {
        if (exists $hash{$nuc}) {
            $trans .= $hash{$nuc};
        }
    }
    return $trans;
}
```

But then...  why bother testing, either.

```
sub trans() {   
    $trans = "";
    for my $nuc (@array) {
        $trans .= $hash{$nuc} // "";
    }
    return $trans;
}
```

And who needs loops anyway?

```
sub trans() {   
    return join '', map { $hash{$_} // '' } @array;
}
```

Comment: Nice way of explanation! I was wondering what's the significance of `// ""`. Can you please brief it for me?

Comment: @jkshah : `//` is the 'defined-or' operator. If the left-hand side evaluates to false, the right-hand side is returned. See [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) for more

Comment: @Zaid Thanks for details! I knew `||` and `&&` but TIL new operator `//`

Comment: As a final step, one might say "Why bother with a subroutine in the first place?"

Comment: Correction in above comment: "If the left-hand side evaluates to __undefined__"

Answer (score 6):

One more way to do it is with a hash slice:

```
sub trans() {   
  return join '', @hash{@array};
}
```

Note that this will complain about uninitialized values if `@array` contains values which are not existing keys in `%hash` and you have `warnings` enabled.  (You *do* have `warnings` enabled, don't you?)  Depending on the rules for your data, this may be either a bug (in which case adding `no warnings` to the `sub` will resolve it) or a feature.

Comment: perhaps `@hash{grep defined $hash{$_}, @array}` to filter out non existing keys, and prevent new keys being added to hash.